# Insertar registros desde otra tabla en Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo 2 tablas: conductor y conductor_aux quiero insertar en la tabla conductor los registros que me hagan falta y se encuentren en la tabla conductor_aux.

EJEMPLO: la tabla conductor tiene 500 registro y la tabla conductor_aux tiene 750 registros, por la tanto tengo 250 registros que están en la tabla conductor_aux y necesito insertarlos en la tabla conductor.

identifico los registros duplicados:

```
select * from conductor_aux as t1
left join conductor as t2 on (t1.c_cedula = t2.c_cedula)
where t2.c_cedula is not null
```

Pero no he podido lograr hacer el INSERT

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy genérica y no da muchos detalles para poderte ayudar; además que no es muy coherente con el título.

Comment: Voy a editarla y a explicar con plastilina

Comment: Puedes hacer algo como esto
insert into Tabla
select * from conductor_aux as t1
left join conductor as t2 on (t1.c_cedula = t2.c_cedula)
where t2.c_cedula is not null

Comment: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad, ya existe la llave. está tratando de insertar los que ya están en la otra tabla, solo quiero insertar los que hagan falta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenia una duda similar y encontré esta pagina:
https://apex-developers.com/2018/07/11/copiar-datos-sin-cursores/

En esa pagina se da un código de ejemplo para insertar datos de una tabla a otra con una sintaxis sencilla.
Se que en realidad la pagina no es sobre Postgresql, pero lo probé en dicho y funcionó.
Espero que esta respuesta te de una base para lograr lo que buscas.

La pagina da el siguiente ejemplo:

```
insert into 
top_sales(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, HIREDATE) 
select EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, HIREDATE 
from emp  
WHERE sal > 3000
```

No se muy bien como funcionan los JOINS en este caso, pero escribí este querry basado en lo anterior (NO está probado y NO estoy seguro si es lo que buscas):

```
INSERT INTO 
conductor(*) 
SELECT * 
FROM conductor_aux 
WHERE c_cedula IS NOT null AND c_cedula NOT IN
(SELECT c_cedula FROM conductor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede recurrir a la siguiente solución. Si no presenta diferencias en ambas tablas, el INSERT ejecutará sin afectar la tabla.

```
create table a( id number, value varchar2(10));
insert into a values (1,'a');
insert into a values (2,'b');
insert into a values (3,'c');
insert into a values (4,'d');

create table b( id number, value varchar2(10));
insert into b values (1,'a');
insert into b values (4,'d'); 

-- insert para balancear la tabla b
insert into b 
select a.* from a left outer join b on a.id = b.id where b.id is null;
```